# plot 3d data in Matlab

Tags: matlab, plot, 3d

I'm trying to plot data on a 3D graph using the waterfall function.  Here's some example code that isn't working properly:

```
x=0:.1:1;
y(1,:) = exp(x);
y(2,:) = exp(2*x);
z = [1,2];
waterfall(x,y,z);
```

I'm trying to plot each curve on it's own z dimension, but I'm not formatting the waterfall command properly.  I think I could also use a "mesh" function, but I can't get that working either.

Comment: Its not clear what you want really. Can you show us an image of your desired outcome? I don't see how `plot` is not what you want.

Comment: Here's an example: https://i.imgur.com/WJAOYsl.png, maybe plot would work.

Comment: Just use either `plot` or `plot3` , plot each of them separatedly, use `hold on`

Answer (score 1):

This is the answer

```
x=0:.1:1;
Z(1,:) = exp(x);
Z(2,:) = exp(2*x);
[X,Y] = meshgrid(x,1:size(Z,1));
waterfall(X,Y,Z)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use:

```
x=0:.1:1;
y(1,:) = exp(x);
y(2,:) = exp(2*x);
z = [1,2];
hold on
plot(x,y(1,:),z(1))
plot(x,y(2,:),z(2))
```

But I'm not sure if that's your desired output.

Comment: I'm totally agree with Andy and Ander. Almost sure that you can use plot.

Comment: I get an error: "Data must be a single matrix Y or a list of pairs X,Y.".   Also, is there a way to plot this with a single plot command?  In general I will have several traces to plot.

Comment: I'm trying to get something that looks like the waterfall example: https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/waterfall.html, but I don't understand how to format the data.

Comment: I figured it out finally:x=0:.1:1;
Z(1,:) = exp(x);
Z(2,:) = exp(2*x);
[X,Y] = meshgrid(x,1:size(Z,1));
waterfall(X,Y,Z)